# How to setup Spotify local files from secondary partition or external drive?

Tags: spotify, jdownloader

I have a linux/windows dualboot, and I have all my personal files in a separate partition, but when I tried to setup spotify local files the media folder doesn't appear. The same happens with JDownloader if I want to download something automatically to that partition. (is this because linux can't use other partitions like windows does?) INSERT SORRY FOR MY ENGLISH xD

Ubuntu 20.04 (and ubuntu based distros)

Comment: I don't know about your system, and even if I did I don't know if I could tell you how, but have you tried to create a symbolic link?

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a KDE/Neon forum.

Comment: GNU/Linux can use almost any partitions (more in fact than windows can) though of course there are *pros* and *cons* to any *fs* chosen (ie. native or via additional kernel module (driver). It just needs to be setup correctly.  You're off-topic however, only Kubuntu is on-topic here (ie. Ubuntu and *flavors* of Ubuntu)

Comment: @lqlarry I tried but this happened: "Unable to run the command specified. The file or folder /home/username*/Downloads/SPOTIFYMUSIC does not exist." and the original directory is: /media/username*/Partition2/SPOTIFYMUSIC/